# zombie.js: how to see complete (i.e. generated) html

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, zombie.js

I'm using CKEditor and I'd like to do some functional tests. The problem is that CKEditor somehow appends itself to a TEXTAREA tag and by means of javascript adds elements to the DOM which I can see, i.e. in Mozilla in "View Generated Source" menu.

However, doing tests with Zombie, I can not see the generated code no matter how long I wait until page loads (I have a-tags only in DOM elements added by CKEditor)

```
     browser.wait(function(arg){
        return arg.document.querySelector('a');
      }(browser), 
      function(arg){
        console.log(arg.document.innerHTML);
      }(browser));
```

where `browser = new Zombie({debug: true, runScripts: true});`

Though the page is loaded, it seems to contain ONLY static code that was "hardcoded", but no code that is added by means of javascript by CKEditor.

So, the question is: is it possible to load the document in such a way that Zombie sees elements that are loaded dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

Try `browser.html()`. see section [Hunting](http://zombie.labnotes.org/#Hunting)

```
console.log(browser.html());
```

Answer (score 0):

I just have the same problem and found a solution... In case somebody stops here :)

Indeed, `browser.html()` doesn't refresh the html.

You must use xpath and get outerHTML. Try to get the node with xpath like this `browser.xpath('/html')`. Then you can get the `outerHTML` of it.

I use Mink (PHP) so I don't have the exact javascript code, but I give you the idea...